# How to add many projects in to single git repository?

Tags: ubuntu, git, bitbucket

I want to add two existing projects into single git repository. Already I have added one project in to repository now I want to add second project without affecting the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option via `--orphan` branch. Viz manual:

```
--orphan
    Create a new orphan branch, named <new_branch>, started from
    <start_point> and switch to it. The first commit made on this new
    branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history
    totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.
```

Its also well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14679614/whats-the-best-practice-for-putting-multiple-projects-in-a-git-repository